# SQL Server FullText Search not returning expected rows

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2016, fulltext-index

I am practicing using FullText Search on SQL Server 2016. Below is a complete code of the steps to reproduce my problem. I don't understand why none of my queries return any results (if you run these steps, don't forget to drop the FTSEARCH database when you are done).

Note that I set STOPLIST=OFF on purpose because I want to search numeric values and numbers are included in the system stoplist

```
--1. Confirm FullText is installed
SELECT 
    CASE FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Full-Text installed.' 
        ELSE 'Full-Text is NOT installed.' 
    END;

--2. Create DB for testing
CREATE DATABASE FTSEARCH

--3. Enable FullText Search
USE FTSEARCH
GO

EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'; 

-- Confirm that FullTextSearch is enabled
SELECT is_fulltext_enabled
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()

--4. Create fulltext catalog
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG FullTextCatalog AS DEFAULT;

-- Verify catalog exists 
SELECT *
FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs

--5. Create sample table and populate some data
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Test_FT_Search]') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [dbo].[Test_FT_Search] 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
(
[PKID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
[Account_Number] [nvarchar] (16)  NULL,
[Code] [nvarchar] (6)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Test_FT_Search] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_PKID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([PKID]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
(
    [Account_Number],
    [Code]
)
VALUES
( N'4445002020875',  N'0A6133' ),
( N'4445002020883',  N'0B6133' ),
( N'4445002020891',  N'0C6134' ),
( N'4445002020909',  N'0F6135' ),
( N'4445002020917',  N'0F6136' )

--6. Create FullText Index
--   NOTE: the STOPLIST is OFF on purpose because I want to search on numbers
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON  [dbo].[Test_FT_Search] (
    [Account_Number],
    [Code]
) 
KEY INDEX  [PK_PKID]
WITH 
    CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, 
    STOPLIST=OFF
;

--7. Force FullText index population
ALTER FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[Test_FT_Search] START FULL POPULATION

--8. Perform some searches

-- None of these queries return any resuls
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
WHERE CONTAINS([Account_Number],'20208') ;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
WHERE CONTAINS([Account_Number],'444500') ;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
WHERE CONTAINS([Code],'F6') ;

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
WHERE CONTAINS([Code],'3') ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CONTAINS:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql)

• A word or phrase.

• The prefix of a word or phrase.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
WHERE CONTAINS([Account_Number],'4445002020891'); --a word or phrase

SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Test_FT_Search]
WHERE CONTAINS([Account_Number],'"44450020208*"') ; --prefix of word: prefix+asterisk in double quotes
```

Comment: Thank you @lptr, does this mean that FullText search doesn't support the kind of functionality I want -- pattern search in the strings?